# NodeJS debugging with Chrome Devtools using --inspect vs --inspect-brk

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

We can start the NodeJS server with either of the following commands:
`node --inspect app.js`
or
`node --inspect-brk app.js`

We have to debug the code because we have encountered a RuntimeError and we have added a breakpoint at the root of the server's source code.

What should be the best practice to do that, in combination with Chrome DevTools?

When tested, I noticed that with `node --inspect app.js` is a bit more difficult to debug properly because it pauses execution if it is an attached debugger and sometimes the execution could finish before I have a chance to attach Chrome DevTools.

With `node --inspect-brk app.js`, it gives me enough time to attach the debugger.